# DLL cannot be found because the file name is different than the one referenced?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I have been baffled on how can this be happening.

So heres the deal, im trying to play a V2M chiptune with a dll called NV2.dll

Its referenced, and I used its functions like normal.
BUT when i try to run the application i get

> Unable to load DLL 'V2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The referenced DLL i used is called NV2, I have checked it, the assembly goes by NV2, not V2, why is it trying to load a dll with a different name?!

Comment: Is it a managed dll? Maybe that's one of its dependencies (dependency walker can help you)? How do you `[DllImport(..)]` the functions, if that dll is managed?

Comment: I didn't use '[DllImport]', just dropped it in VS as reference and used its functions, the usual; The DLL should have no other dependancies.

Comment: Sorry, meant *unmanaged in the last part. Download link for the dll for reference? Pretty sure there are dependencies if that error shows up.

Comment: Sure http://flan.s-ul.eu/F6Oz2T07

Comment: Ofcourse, the dependency on the `V2.dll` can be clearly seen in the dll, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/xwnbh.png . Now this is probably a managed wrapper dll for an unmanaged dll (the `V2.dll`), so the `NV2.dll` should have come with the `V2.dll`. You must find that dll on the publishers / developers website where you got the original managed dll from and copy that `V2.dll` into your applications folder (where the .exe) is, then everything will work fine.

Comment: Heres the thing, this worked fine a year ago, also the developer who published this has put up examples aswell using only NV2.dll, no V2.dll exists.

Comment: Oh, interesting thing: There is a `byte[] V2` in the resources of that DLL! You must just write that byte array to disk as `V2.dll` I think. It can be seen e.g. in the telerik's decompiler. It's right there in the `Resources` of that dll. If that's not accessible, I'll dump the dll for you. 
Edit: Drop that again, it does so *itself* in the constructor. See the reverse engineered code at  http://i.stack.imgur.com/kTVsv.png . You must create an instance of that class (`NV2`) first to trigger that code

Comment: I get it now, its a wrapper for V2_DLL, an unmanaged assembly which has these functions http://flan.s-ul.eu/PM14Trfb This is occuring because its trying to write the V2.dll to the system directory but is failing due to priviledges (a common problem with newer Win versions). I'll get that decompiler and work with the unmanaged dll to get this to finally work, thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So obviously, there is a reference to `V2.dll` inside the `NV2.dll`. Either the documentation is just shitty or you didn't notice that part, but inside the constructor of the `NV2` class they try to write that `V2.dll`, which is saved inside the `Resources` of the dll as a `byte[] V2` to disk, namely to the directory `C:\Windows\system32`. Code:

```
    public NV2()
    {
        List<WeakReference> _ENCList = NV2.__ENCList;
        Monitor.Enter(_ENCList);
        try
        {
            NV2.__ENCList.Add(new WeakReference(this));
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_ENCList);
        }
        //Here comes the part that writes the resources
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "\\V2.dll"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        fileStream.Write(Resources.V2, 0, checked((int)Resources.V2.Length));
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Meaning that either in your application you first have to do a

```
  var engine = new NV2(); //triggers the constructor code
```

to trigger that, or you go hardcore on that and dump the `byte[]` from their dll.

I've dumped that file here for you and zipped it: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11263190/V2.zip.html

(You could have done that by saving the project using teleriks decompiler, fixing the errors in the ressources, changing the project to a console project, then coding a Main function like)

```
using System.IO;
using NV2.My.Resources;

namespace NV2
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("V2.dll", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            fileStream.Write(Resources.V2, 0, checked((int)Resources.V2.Length));
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also no need for all that, I just did this and made it work http://flan.s-ul.eu/iNX6BhHz